# What "Is" Barbeque or "BBQ"?

Tags: barbecue

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What styles of barbeque exist in American cuisine?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/20667/what-styles-of-barbeque-exist-in-american-cuisine)

There are many different techniques, practices and (of course) sauces that are given the label "Barbeque" (or BBQ, or Bar-B-Q, or....).

What are the various styles of BBQ, and what distinguishes them?

What (if anything) is/are the common threads that tie them all together?

Comment: No matter what answers you get below, the true nature of BBQ is drinking beer while cooking stuff outside over hot coals.

Comment: which is a question you did not answer....

Comment: Delicious.  BBQ is delicious.  Often, crappy meat made INTO something delicious.

Answer (score 0):

You question has a short answer to it.

Barbeque - What you do on a gas or charcoal grill

BBQ - shredded, pulled or sliced pork, lamb or beef seasoned with a hot pepper and vinegar , mustard based, tomato based or mayo based sauce.

For more on BBQ the BBQ song - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ubTQfr_tyY